# Parsing code on node JS with cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, request, cheerio

I'm trying to parse code with cheerio but i need some help )

Now my parsing look like this:

[image]

Here's how i want see code) I'll be very appreciative if you help me ! :)

```
[ { version: '1.3',
    href: '/download-app/com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon/4_com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-12-26.apk/',
    data: 'Dec. 26, 2016'},
  { version: ' 1.3 ',
    href: '/download-app/com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon/2_com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-12-25.apk/',
    data: 'Dec. 25, 2016'},
    { version: ' 1.2 ',
      href: '/download-app/com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon/3_com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-08-26.apk/',
      data: 'Aug. 26, 2016'} ]
```

HTML code what i'm trying parse :

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
<table class="striped" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<tbody>
<tr><td><a title="download Summer Girl Hair Spa &amp; Salon 1.3 apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-12-26.apk');" href="/download-app/com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon/4_com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-12-26.apk/">1.3</a></td><td>Dec. 26, 2016</td></tr>
<tr><td><a title="download Summer Girl Hair Spa &amp; Salon  1.3   apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-12-25.apk');" href="/download-app/com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon/2_com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-12-25.apk/"> 1.3 </a></td><td>Dec. 25, 2016</td></tr>
<tr><td><a title="download Summer Girl Hair Spa &amp; Salon  1.2   apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-08-26.apk');" href="/download-app/com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon/3_com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-08-26.apk/"> 1.2 </a></td><td>Aug. 26, 2016</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

My code on cheerio (NodeJs) for parsing:

```
   const row = $('.row');
   const version = [];
   const href = [];
   const data = [];

   row.find('tr').each(function (i, e) {
     version.push({"version": $(this).find("td a[title^='download']").text()});
     href.push({"href": $(this).find("td a").attr('href')});
     data.push({"data": $(this).find("td").eq(1).text()});
   });
```

Comment: You need to have only 1 array, and push objects into that array with href, data, version attributes.

Comment: can you write code on question ? please )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map` method and return array of objects where each object is data form current `tr`.

```js
const data = $('.row table tr').map(function() {
  const a = $(this).find('td:first-child a');
  const td = $(this).find('td:last-child');

  return {
    version: a.text(),
    href: a.attr('href'),
    date: td.text()
  }
}).get();

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%;">
<table class="striped" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<tbody>
<tr><td><a title="download Summer Girl Hair Spa &amp; Salon 1.3 apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-12-26.apk');" href="/download-app/com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon/4_com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-12-26.apk/">1.3</a></td><td>Dec. 26, 2016</td></tr>
<tr><td><a title="download Summer Girl Hair Spa &amp; Salon  1.3   apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-12-25.apk');" href="/download-app/com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon/2_com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-12-25.apk/"> 1.3 </a></td><td>Dec. 25, 2016</td></tr>
<tr><td><a title="download Summer Girl Hair Spa &amp; Salon  1.2   apk " onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'download_ver', 'com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-08-26.apk');" href="/download-app/com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon/3_com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-08-26.apk/"> 1.2 </a></td><td>Aug. 26, 2016</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it work ! ) but it still gives me bad fields (like first field) :

`{ version: '', href: undefined, date: 'com.girlsbea...' },
  { version: '1.3',
    href: '/download-app/com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon/4_com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon_2016-12-26.apk/',
    date: 'Dec. 26, 2016' },`

Comment: Maybe the html in your question is not the same as the html you are trying to parse. Otherwise it had to return the same result

Comment: Here's [link](https://www.apkmonk.com/app/com.girlsbeautysalon.android_summerhairsalon/) i think it's the same. i want to remove this excess fields, but don't know how ((

Comment: You need better selector instead of row because there are probably other `row` elements on the page. You need selector that is unique for that part you want to parse.